# How to split a text file based on the number of characters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a big file and want to split the text file into multiple files based on their number of characters. Each file has to have characters lower than 100000.

So for example, input file `test.txt` would turn into ```test1.txt, test2.txt, test3.txt... test1932.txt''' etc.

I have the below logic.

```
with open("test.txt") as inFile:
    sentence = inFile.read().split()

character_count = 0
output_sentence = ""
fileCount = 0
outputName = "test" + fileCount + ".txt"

for word in sentence:
    word = word.replace(",", "")
    character_count = character_count + len(word)
    if character_count < 100000:
        output_sentence = output_sentence + word + " "
    else:
        fileCount = fileCount + 1
        break

with open(outputName, "w") as outputFile:
    outputFile.write(output_sentence)
```

However, I am kind of stuck on how to loop this so that it keep generating new files. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: just write it out in your else clause, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the creation of the files in the loop as well as updating the variable `sentence` for the contents of the current file. How about this:

```
for word in sentence:
    word = word.replace(",", "")
    character_count = character_count + len(word)
    if character_count < 100000:
        output_sentence = output_sentence + word + " "
    else:
        character_count = 0
        outputName = "test" + fileCount + ".txt"

       with open(outputName, "w") as outputFile:
           outputFile.write(output_sentence)

       fileCount = fileCount + 1
       output_sentence = ''
```

Comment: this wouldn't start the count from 0 right? because I want to make sure to keep creating new files after it hits 100000

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open('YourFile.txt', 'r')
c,d = 0,0
s = f.read()
f.close()
w = ""
for ch in s:
    c = c + 1
    w = w + ch
    if c == 100000:
        d = d + 1
        g = open('test'+str(d)+'.txt', 'w')
        g.write(w)
        g.close()
        w = ""
        c = 0
```